# indirect rendering issue on 12.04, using ati driver

Tags: 12.04, ati

I have ubuntu 12.04 64-bit system, when i run glxinfo i see some strange error about indirect rendering and failed to load some lib32/dri/swrast_dri libraries.

Any idea what is going on?

please let me know if i can enhance the relevant information provided in this question

```
$ LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose glxinfo
name of display: :0
libGL: screen 0 does not appear to be DRI2 capable
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib32/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib32/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL error: dlopen /usr/lib32/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (/usr/lib32/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL error: dlopen /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (/usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: reverting to indirect rendering
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: No (If you want to find out why, try setting LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose)
server glx vendor string: ATI
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_OML_swap_method, 
    GLX_SGI_make_current_read, GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGIS_multisample, 
    GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
client glx version string: 1.4
client glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, 
    GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, 
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_swap_control, 
    GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_OML_sync_control, GLX_SGI_make_current_read, 
    GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync, GLX_SGIS_multisample, 
    GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, 
    GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_INTEL_swap_event
GLX version: 1.4
GLX extensions:
    GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, 
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_OML_swap_method, 
    GLX_SGI_make_current_read, GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGIS_multisample, 
    GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, 
    GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap
OpenGL vendor string: ATI Technologies Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon HD 6800 Series 
OpenGL version string: 1.4 (2.1 (4.2.11762 Compatibility Profile Context))
OpenGL extensions:
    GL_ARB_depth_texture, GL_ARB_draw_buffers, GL_ARB_fragment_program, 
    GL_ARB_fragment_program_shadow, GL_ARB_framebuffer_object, GL_ARB_imaging, 
    GL_ARB_multisample, GL_ARB_multitexture, GL_ARB_occlusion_query, 
    GL_ARB_point_parameters, GL_ARB_point_sprite, GL_ARB_shadow, 
    GL_ARB_shadow_ambient, GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp, 
    GL_ARB_texture_compression, GL_ARB_texture_cube_map, 
    GL_ARB_texture_env_add, GL_ARB_texture_env_combine, 
    GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar, GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3, 
    GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat, GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two, 
    GL_ARB_texture_rectangle, GL_ARB_transpose_matrix, GL_ARB_vertex_program, 
    GL_ARB_window_pos, GL_EXT_abgr, GL_EXT_bgra, GL_EXT_blend_color, 
    GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate, GL_EXT_blend_func_separate, 
    GL_EXT_blend_minmax, GL_EXT_blend_subtract, GL_EXT_copy_texture, 
    GL_EXT_draw_range_elements, GL_EXT_fog_coord, GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit, 
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample, GL_EXT_framebuffer_object, 
    GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays, GL_EXT_packed_pixels, GL_EXT_point_parameters, 
    GL_EXT_rescale_normal, GL_EXT_secondary_color, 
    GL_EXT_separate_specular_color, GL_EXT_shadow_funcs, GL_EXT_stencil_wrap, 
    GL_EXT_subtexture, GL_EXT_texture3D, GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc, 
    GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp, GL_EXT_texture_env_add, 
    GL_EXT_texture_env_combine, GL_EXT_texture_env_dot3, GL_EXT_texture_lod, 
    GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias, GL_EXT_texture_mirror_clamp, 
    GL_EXT_texture_object, GL_EXT_texture_rectangle, GL_EXT_vertex_array, 
    GL_ATI_draw_buffers, GL_ATI_texture_env_combine3, 
    GL_ATI_texture_mirror_once, GL_ATIX_texture_env_combine3, 
    GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat, GL_INGR_blend_func_separate, 
    GL_NV_texture_rectangle, GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap, 
    GL_SGIS_texture_border_clamp, GL_SGIS_texture_edge_clamp, 
    GL_SGIS_texture_lod, GL_SGIX_shadow_ambient, GL_SUN_multi_draw_arrays
```

However, i did a search for that library and it is somewhere else:

```
$ locate swrast_dri.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so
```

Answer (score 1):

You get two errors there: first it cant load `/usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so` and it can't load `/usr/lib32/dri/swrast_dri.so failed` also. To fix the first you can try to make a symbolic link to make the location it needs points to the real location of the files:

```
sudo ln -s  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri /usr/lib/dri
```

I don't know if this is the best way, but if it doesn work you can delete the symlink created

```
sudo rm /usr/lib/dri
```

The next error seems to be related to the fact it cannot find the 32bit version of that libraries. You can try to install it using (`libgl1-mesa-dri` is the package that provides that file in my system):

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i just did install libgl1-mesa-dri:i386, but the only library in that folder is `/usr/lib32/dri/fglrx_dri.so`; swrast_dri.so is still missing. Not sure if i should symlink it to the x86_64 version

Comment: that's weird, in 12.10 that package installs that file in `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/`. You can try using `apt-file search swrast_dri.so` to see which packages provide it in your system.

Comment: 1st row: `libgl1-mesa-dri: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so`

2nd row: `libgl1-mesa-dri-dbg: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so`

Comment: i just downloaded the 12.04 version of libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 and yes, that file is present in the same place as 12.10 (`/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/`). Check again

Comment: the library is there! so i just need to make a symlink to the other path..

Comment: ok now glxinfo gives this error: `libGL error: dlopen /usr/lib32/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (/usr/lib32/dri/swrast_dri.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32)`

Comment: i changed the symlink in /usr/lib32/dri to point to the x86_64 library and it doesn't give the warning anymore (i know, weird!) so the only remaining error is the cryptic and unhelpful: `libGL: screen 0 does not appear to be DRI2 capable`

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by uninstalling the old one:

```
sudo /usr/share/ati/amd-uninstall.sh --force
```

then rebooted the machine, then installed [latest 12.10 version](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx)

rebooted again (who said that in linux you don't have to reboot?)

and now the context is direct